# Closed form of power series with Gamma function as coefficient

Tags: power-series, gamma-function

Is it possible to get the closed form of the below series?
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{x^{p(k+1)}}{\Gamma(p(k+1)+1)}$$
with $p \in (0, 1)$, and $\Gamma(x)$ is the Gamma function.

I know that without $p$, the formula is just $1-e^{-x}$.

And I also tried substitution $y = x^p$.

In addition, searching stackexchange and google, I think this may relate to generalized binomial theorem.

Comment: Hoping that you enjoy monsters, use Wolfram Alpha. I made it for $p=5/2$. Cheers

Comment: I got timeout on Wolfram Alpha since I am not a pro user :(

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, Congras, that is very helpful info, I will try Wolfram again when I got opportunity. Do you have any picture of that to share?

Comment: This is known as [Mittag-Leffler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_function) (single-parameter case).

Comment: @metamorphy, great! That is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f_p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{x^{p(k+1)}}{\Gamma[p(k+1)+1]}$$

The very first ones are "simple"
$$f_1(x)=1-e^{-x} \qquad f_2(x)=1-\cos (x)$$ $$f_3(x)=-\frac{1}{3} e^{-x} \left(1-3 e^x+2 e^{3 x/2} \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}
   x}{2}\right)\right)$$
$$f_4(x)=1-\cos \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \cosh \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$ For $p>4$, the only expressions are generalized hypergeometric functions. I give you the very first in order you see the patterns
$$f_5(x)=1-\,
   _0F_4\left(;\frac{1}{5},\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5};-\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)^5
   \right)$$
$$f_6(x)=1-\,
   _0F_5\left(;\frac{1}{6},\frac{2}{6},\frac{3}{6},\frac{4}{6},\frac{5}{6};-\left(\frac{x}{6}\right)^6\right)$$
$$f_7(x)=1-\,
   _0F_6\left(;\frac{1}{7},\frac{2}{7},\frac{3}{7},\frac{4}{7},\frac{5}{7},\frac
   {6}{7};-\left(\frac{x}{7}\right)^7\right)$$ making the general form to be
$$f_p(x)=1-\,
   _0F_{p-1}\left(;\frac{1}{p},\frac{2}{p},\cdots,\frac{p-1}{p};-\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)^p\right)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am wondering how to solve this when $p$ is fraction (or even irrational), e.g. $0.5$.

Comment: @monomial. Let me try with half-integers. I shall be back ... if anything interesting.